# Hide enum values in derived class

Tags: c#

I have the following

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Warning,
    Info,
    Error
}

public class CalculationMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MessageType Type { get; set; }

}

public class ValidationMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MessageType Type { get; set; }

    public string ErrorValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a base class from which both of these classes are derived, however I have a problem with the enum as a ValidationMessage can be Error / Warning / Info but a CalculationMessage can only be Warning or Info.

How is this best achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define two enums ... You can not 'limit' the values for an enum. Maybe you can try to add a private setter to the property and add a method like SetMessageType(MessageType Type) for setting the value.

Comment: Enums + OO don't mix well. If you want any functionality that can apply to any type of base class message (say to route based on message type) you need those additional enums types. Were it me I'd make a string and be done with it. But then I think enums are over used in general with only marginal benefit.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a parameter validation in the setter:

```
set
{
  if(value == MessageType.Warning || value == MessageType.Info)
  {
    this.messageType = value;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  }
}
```

This is, however, a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. Therefore be careful and think if there may be a way around (e.g. not making the setter public at all, but determing the `MessageType` internally).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, this is the answer I found while digging but thought I'd confirm it.